# How to disable Opportunity locking on Red Hat 5/CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, nas, redhat-enterprise-linux, cifs, modprobe

Syslog returns the error "kernel:  CIFS VFS: Write2 ret -13, wrote 0" when I'm using the software under cifs fylesystem, managed by NAS server.

CIFS Version is 1.60RH.

I saw that the options OplockEnabled and LookupCacheEnabled are set to 1 (default).

How can I disable this configuration?

Is it related with this error?

I already tested the following commands but with no effects:

```
# modprobe cifs enable_oplocks=0
```

Added a line to a file in /etc/modprobe.d containing the following line:

```
install cifs /sbin/modprobe –ignore-install cifs; echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/OplockEnabled ;
```

Thanks in advance.